# How to create Date from Components in Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift

I've stored day in a month and time. I am creating a notification and I need to do a little calculation and then create a date. I stuck at the part where I "glue" all parts into `Date` so I can create fireDate.

I'm not really sure how this works although I'm trying to figure it out using Apple documentation. As I gathered I need `DateComponents` but then I don't know how to proceed. There is only an `init()` method that takes so many parameters.

For now I have very little code:

```
let calendar = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian)
let components = DateComponents()
calendar.date(from: components)
```

Can somebody please clarify this for me?
Thanks a bunch.

Comment: What is your input and what do you want as an output?

Comment: So, I have `Int` as day in a month and I have data from date picker (I use it to get time). I need to create a date from that separate data. I'm not sure how should I achieve that.

Comment: Can you post the output which you get from your date picker. Only a day as Int cannot help you to create a date

Comment: All parameters are optional so you can simply write `DateComponents(month:10, day:14)` but consider that a date without the year component can cause unexpected behavior.

Comment: Date is: 2016-10-14 17:36:56 +0000
That is from the date picker. Okay, so I need to modify that date if I'm not wrong. How do I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you want to create a notification to be fired at a specific date. You'll need to create a `UNCalendarNotificationTrigger` from `DateComponents`. So given a date, you would need to create a `DateComponents` object from that date.

```
// Assuming your UIDatePicker is named `datePicker`
let triggerDate = datePicker.date
let dateComponents = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.year, .month, .day, .hour, .minute, .second], from: triggerDate)
let trigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: dateComponents, repeats: false)
```

Here is the complete code you would need to fire a notification at a certain date:

```
let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
content.title = "Notification Title"
let triggerDate = datePicker.date
let dateComponents = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.year, .month, .day, .hour, .minute, .second], from: triggerDate)
let trigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: dateComponents, repeats: false)
let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: nil, content: content, trigger: trigger)
UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(request)
```

Comment: This answer really helped! I just used day component with my `Int`

Comment: Hey what If I want to preset a date such as 9:30Am instead of using a date from a Picker. How would you do that? @jawwad?